# Looping through and extracting substring

Tags: python, list, index-error

Why am I getting list index out of range?

```
ip_list = []
path = r'''mail.log'''
with open(path, 'r') as log:
  for line in log:
      if "SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure" in line:
          ip_address = line.split("warning: unknown[")[1].split("]")[0]
          ip_list.append(ip_address)
```

Output:

```
...
ip_address = line.split("warning: unknown[")[1].split("]")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your log file?

Comment: likely because some of your log lines does not contain "warning: unknown[". When python tries to split it, you get a list of length 1. When you try to access the second element over here "line.split("warning: unknown[")[1]", the error is thrown.

Comment: Print the `line` and check how it looks just before you get the exception.